# Confidence interval of episode duration frequencies

Tags: r, count, confidence-interval

I have the episode duration data (in days)

```
dur<-c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 10, 1, 1, 2, 2, 18, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 11, 25, 17, 2, 2, 9, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 363, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Which means in one instance the episode duration was 1 days, 2 days, 1 days etc etc

`table(dur)` summarizes the duration data (12 instances of 1 day, 20 instances of 2 days etc)

`freq.table<-(table(dur)/sum(table(dur)))` gives me the frequency of the observed durations of episodes (point estimates).

How can I get confidence intervals of `freq.table`  in R? What would be the most appropriate way for this kind of data?

Edit: I am interested in estimating the CI of the frequency of episode durations of 1, 2, ..., n days

Comment: CI for what? The mean? Each element in the table?

Comment: A confidence interval gives the uncertainty of an estimate. What are you estimating?

Comment: Please see edit. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you know what a (statistical) estimate is. Currently, my understanding is that you want to estimate the distribution of the durations and would like to have a confidence interval for that distribution. Is that interpretation correct?

Comment: Thanks. Please see edit. I am interested in the CI of the frequency of the episode durations.

Comment: You still haven't stated the problem in unambiguous statistical terms.

Answer (score 2):

A fast and easy way to get CIs for proportions in R is the function `binom.test` as in

```
dur <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 11, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 
   1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 10, 1, 1, 2, 2, 18, 2,
   2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, 11, 25, 17, 2, 2, 9,
   3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 363, 1, 1, 2, 2)

t <- table(dur)
n <- length(dur)

ci <- sapply(t, function(x) binom.test(x, n, conf.level = .95)$conf.int)
rownames(ci) <- c("lower", "upper")
print(ci)
```

That is supposing, that the data forming process for each episode is anything like a binomial process.

**Edit after first comment**

As Roland has pointed out in an earlier comment above, you have not stated the problem in inambigous statistical terms, so I made some assumptions. I suppose Roland would suggest trying to find a distribution for all the possible durations as a whole system. Considerung a mode on 2 and the existence of an observation with value 363 this is unlikely to be a common distribution like poisson or binomial etc. Knowing nothing about the data generating process I estimated a confidence interval for each observed outcome on it's own, not regarding the distribution as a whole. For each observed outcome I stated that I assumed a binomial distribution which you should look up before you use my proposition for an answer for anything serious.

Comment: There are assumptions involved that should be stated clearly. Also, note that these are pointwise confidence intervals.